# Reject packets in pf after a connection consumed a certain amount of traffic

Tags: openbsd, pf

In `pf` you can limit the bandwidth that is consumed (by for example ssh) using [queues](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/queueing.html).

I am hosting a UDP Service ([Discard Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discard_Protocol)) which can easily eat up all my traffic when a client transfers data.

Is there a way in `pf` to limit a connection or drop packets after a client connection consumed, lets say, 1GB of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with pf alone—you’d have to couple it with something like pflow(4) and related to handle the traffic accounting.  You might also be able to cook something up with some output from pfctl.

Comment: You are right. I set up a `pf` rule for discard protocol with a `label discard` to identify how much traffic was consumed with `pfctl -sl`. After a certian amount of traffic I block all incoming traffic on udp port 9. Thank you!